# Appcelerator change app name deploys two instances of the app

Tags: android, crash, appcelerator, rename

I have an application in Appcelerator where I have attempted to change the name.  Works fine in iOS, but deploys 2 versions on android devices and emulators and crashes immediately.

I have changed the entries in the tiapp.xml files and the manifest to match the new name, and also changed the manifest file to match the new name. Anyone who has resolved this issue I would love some insight.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who runs into this, I have found my own answer.  This link was most helpful. https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/122112/problem-installing-application-on-android-phone Apparently because I took the name of my application from two words to one word the activity went from camel case to all lower case.  For example if the app was named My App and was changed to MyApp the Manifest would need to be changed from android:name=".MyAppActivity" to android:name=".MyappActivity".  Hope this helps someone out there.